# XCode 4.1 no longer seems to create header file when you create c++ file, any idea how to make a template?

Tags: c++, xcode, xcode4

Why does Apple seem to hate C++ so much; this always worked in Xcode in prior versions, and still works with .m files. Why do they remove features people actually use every day? Not everyone just uses Objective-C by itself. Is there some way to make the file template do this again?

Comment: Hmm I found the templates at /Developer/Library/Xcode/Templates/File Templates/C and C++/C++ File.xctemplate
C++ File.xctemplate and could combine the c++ one with a copy of the header .h file with a little editing. Silly Apple.

Comment: Totally agree, removing a little check box that people invariably use... why.

Answer (score 10):

The solution is to go to "/Developer/Library/Xcode/Templates/File Templates/C and C++", and copy **__*FILEBASENAME*__**.h  from "Header File.xctemplate" into both "C File.xctemplate" and "C++ File.xctemplate"

No idea why this would've been changed in Xcode 4.1...

Comment: I also changed the `#include` statements to `#include "__FILEBASENAME__.h"`

Comment: Also should go to "/Applications/Xcode.app/Developer/Library/Xcode/Templates/File Templates/C and C++"

Comment: Should of been `#include "___FILEBASENAME___.h"`. It's three '_'